# MongoDB and REST

Tags: node.js, angularjs, rest, mean-stack

I have this Schema: (I am working with MEAN stack)

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    randomText: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

A jade file:

```
.someClass Some default text
input.form-control.yfname(type="text", ng-model="user.firstName")
input.form-control.ylname(type="text", ng-model="user.lastName")
button Register
```

I want when I click Register button , whatever firstName and lastName is entered , to be saved to the database and the text from .someClass to be stored in the randomText field. Also I want to be able to find it later with db.collection.find but I am not sure how. Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You haven't included any details of the Express routes you've defined, nor have you included any client-side JavaScript. If you're asking for details on how to implement the routes on the server side, then just search Google for a tutorial on using Express.